# How can lilypond-book accept TeX input files with absolute path?

Tags: lilypond

I have a minimal non-working example in my local folder /private/tmp/LyTeX/. My file source.lytex there contains

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{/private/tmp/LyTeX/common.tex}
\begin{lilypond}
\relative c { c d e }
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

It inputs a LaTeX file common.tex with some shared settings,
for the minimal non-working example, the content is irrelevant, so I set its content here to

```
whatever
```

When I call
`lilypond-book -o /private/tmp/LyTeX/outdir source.lytex`
or
`lilypond-book --output=/private/tmp/LyTeX/outdir source.lytex`,
despite the output directory setting, I always get the failure:

> lilypond-book (GNU LilyPond) 2.24.1
>
> Reading `/private/tmp/LyTeX/source.lytex'

[…]

> Processing include `/private/tmp/LyTeX/common.tex'
>
> lilypond-book: error: Output would overwrite input file; use --output.

Note that there is no failure if common.tex is input using a relative path.